# IOS Objective C Grandparent as delegate

Tags: ios, objective-c, delegates

I have a "GrandParentViewController" that has all methods of my application.  I have a subview "ParentViewController" that contains a few subviews "ChildVC" for which I want the methods to be delegated to the "GrandParentViewController".  I currently have a delegate chain from the childVC >> parentVC >> GrandparentVC but it feels wrong.  What is the IOS way of doing this?

Comment: Consider NSNotifications

Comment: What does "...that has all methods of my application" mean? It sounds kinda scary.

Answer (score 1):

It seems that [single responsibility principle](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Single_responsibility_principle) is violated in your code. Maybe it is a good idea to split GrandParentViewController to several classes?

Also make sure you know what is **protocol** in Objective-C and how it should be used.

I do not recommend to use NSNotifications since it is good and was designed for other cases then direct delegation.

Answer (score 0):

I wouldn't say that there's a set iOS way. I do something similar to what you described because it's the natural way that my VCs should be related. Go with whatever paradigm helps you keep your code clean for future changes, modularized for reusability, and of course, functional.

I will say that if any communications between VCs don't fit with your paradigm, don't force it. Use NSNotifications instead.